# How can I properly track and delete class objects in Python?

Tags: python, pyqt, garbage-collection, del

I am working on a Python GUI (see some incomplete code snippets below) where I dynammically need to generate and delete tabs and connected class instances.

What I try to achieve is to display information retrieved from files within a certrain folder. I navigate to this folder and list  for all relevant files in this folder. In the main window of the app, I display this list of relevant files. Furthermore, for each file in this list, I generate a class instance (here the class OsciCOntroller). This class instance holds the information of the corresponding file, and additional information. In the main window, by clicking onto the list of files, I can choose which content to display. The contect is displayed as a tab, and, by selecting several files, I am able to display several tabs simulataneously.

This is how the GUI looks like, with tabs and file list

[image]

Upon start, I generate a QTabWidget osci_tab_holder to display the tabs lateron. Also, several parameters from the main window are handed over to the OsciController class. Everytime I select a new folder, _on_selectionchange_dataType() is evoked to clear the list of osci_tabs, delete each former tab widgets, also clear the QTabWidget and generate new OsciController instances, which are added to the osci_tabs weakref.

So, every time I maneuvre to a new folder, the old OsciControllers can be deleted. However, I find that only when restarting the app these instances are actually open for the garbage collector to be dumped. So somehow, I am not realeasing all the instances correctly.

Can anyone of you provide an idea/roadmap on what else I could try, or what I am doing wrong?

Cheers, and many thanks!
Lukas

```
class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    osci_tabs = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        OsciController._static_ax = self._static_ax
        OsciController.toolbar = self.toolbar
        self._setup_osci_case()

    def _setup_osci_case(self):
        self.osci_tabs_holder = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.osci_backlayer.addWidget(self.osci_tabs_holder)


    def _on_selectionchange_dataType(self,item):
            self.osci_tabs.clear()
            OsciController.list_of_osciController.clear()    
            self.osci_tabs_holder.clear()

            for osci_file in itemsTextList:
                self.osci_tabs[osci_file.text()] = OsciController(osci_file, self.osci_tabs_holder)

class OsciController(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    list_of_osciController = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()
    _counter = 0

    def __init__(self, item, parent = None):
        gc.collect()
        OsciController._counter += 1
        super(OsciController, self).__init__(parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.list_of_osciController[item.text()] = self

    def __del__(self):
        OsciController._counter -= 1
```

Comment: Python (CPython at least) primarily uses a reference counter for garbage collection - as long as there's a reference to an object (that can itself be accessed one way or another), the object will stay alive. References are created each time you bind an object to a name or add it to a container. The `del` statement does NOT delete an object, it only delete the name (or container index or key), hence decrementing the reference count. IOW, your for loop in `on_selectionchange` is only a waste of CPU cycles - it creates a new reference then remove it, so it's functionally a no-op.

Comment: Hey bruno, thank you very much for contributing. Indeed, this loop is useless, it is removed now. However, the OsciControll object would still continue to life.